# Given moments $\langle \xi^k \rangle$ find moments $\langle (\log \xi)^k \rangle$, without knowing the distribution for $x$

Tags: statistics, random-variables

The problem: random variable $\xi$ is distributed according to an unknown distribution $f(\xi)$. There's no guarantee that its characteristic function $\phi (\omega) = \langle e^{i \omega \xi} \rangle$ exists (it most likely doesn't due to the zero radius of convergence). However, we have (possibly infinitely) many moments of $\xi$ at our disposal,

$$
\xi_k \equiv \langle \xi^k \rangle > 0
$$

I would like to infer the values of the lowest $N$ moments of random variable $x$ ($x_k \equiv \langle x^k \rangle$), where $e^x = \xi$. Unfortunately, the direct calculation is not possible
$$
\langle x \rangle = \langle \log \xi \rangle \overset{?}{=} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \langle (\xi-1)^k \rangle = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{j = 0}^k \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{k} \xi_j
$$
because, in addition to some more complicated algebra, the radius of convergence of the log sum is 1, but the moments $\xi_k$ grow even faster, so this sum actually diverges.

So that made me think: maybe we can take the series expansion for $e^x$ and chop it at a finite power, then use the resulting set of (linear) equations to solve for various moments of $x$. For example, if we chop at $\langle x^4 \rangle$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\xi_1 = \langle e^x \rangle &\approx 1 + x_1 + \frac{x_2}{2!} + \frac{x_3}{3!} + \frac{x_4}{4!} \\
\xi_2 = \langle e^{2x} \rangle &\approx 1 + 2 x_1 + \frac{2^2 x_2}{2!} + \frac{2^3 x_3}{3!} + \frac{2^4 x_4}{4!} \\
\xi_3 = \langle e^{3x} \rangle &\approx 1 + 3 x_1 + \frac{3^2 x_2}{2!} + \frac{3^3 x_3}{3!} + \frac{3^4 x_4}{4!} \\
\xi_4 = \langle e^{4x} \rangle &\approx 1 + 4 x_1 + \frac{4^2 x_2}{2!} + \frac{4^3 x_3}{3!} + \frac{4^4 x_4}{4!} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
(here we're solving a set of 4 linear equations in $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ with given known values of $\xi_{1,2,3,4}$)

However, this method doesn't work at all. I took a simple example where $\xi$ is generated from a lognormal distribution with $\sigma = 0.4, \mu = - \sigma^2 / 2$ (so that $\xi_1 = 1$), so the first values of $\xi_k$ are
$$
(1, 1.17351, 1.61607, 2.6117, 4.95303, 11.0232, 28.7892, ...)
$$

When I set up the linear problem and gradually increase the number of terms in the expansion for $exp (k x)$, the resulting solutions for $x_k$ vary wildly, change signs and eventually seem to explode to infinity. The result is only roughly correct with two terms, when I get $x_1 = -0.0867554, x_2 = 0.173511$ (the correct values are $x_1 = -0.08, x_2 = 0.1664$). I assume if it fails for a simple example like this one, it just doesn't work in general.

What is the correct way to tackle this problem?

Note: practically, for actual datasets with finitely many elements, the moments $\xi_k$, for high values of $k$ eventually stop following the distribution they're drawn from, and instead roughly give the value of the maximum element: $\xi_k \approx \frac{1}{N} \xi_{\text{max}}^k$. This slows down the growth of $\xi_k$ for large $k$, especially if $\xi$ are from a lognormal-like distribution (whose ideal moments grow much faster than that).

Comment: There's no guarantee the characteristic function exists? The characteristic function always exists

Comment: @Andrew I misspoke. The characteristic function exists, but might not be analytic at the origin, hence I wouldn't tackle this by analyzing the characteristic function of the distribution for $\xi$. If a succesful strategy of obtaining the moments of $\log \xi$ involves using the characteristic function, I'd be curious to see how it works.